# pass the error message of multer to the other router

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I tried to handle the file upload error, but not be with new Error.
Since, I want to send it back and display on the upload page.

In my code, I want to pass the fileFilter's error message to the router('car_controller.car_register_post), and then want to use it as req.body or others on html.

But I cannot find the way to do it from everywhere...
can anybody help me?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");

var car_controller = require('../controllers/CarController');

var storage = multer.memoryStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '')
    },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("File format should be PNG,JPG,JPEG"), false); // I want to pass this error message to html
  }
};

var upload = multer({ 
  storage: storage, 
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});


/* GET users listing. */

router.post('/car/register', upload.single('image_file'), car_controller.car_register_post);
```